# How to attach a lambda authorizer to api gateway V2 connect route in aws terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I´m trying to attach my lambda authorizer (already created) into my $connect route. It creates correctly the authorizer, but it doesn´t fill up the "Auth" automatically on my route request. It looks like it doesn't get the reference for my authorizer.
[Authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Syr.png)

This is my **connect**:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "ConnectRoute" {
  api_id         = aws_apigatewayv2_api.api_gateway_websocket.id
  route_key      = "$connect"
  operation_name = "ConnectRoute"
  authorizer_id  = aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer.authorizer.id
  depends_on = [
   aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer.authorizer
  ]
}
```

And this is my **authorizer**:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_authorizer" "authorizer" {
  api_id           = aws_apigatewayv2_api.api_gateway_websocket.id
  authorizer_type  = "REQUEST"
  authorizer_uri   = var.lambda_authorizer_uri
  identity_sources = ["route.request.querystring.authorization"]
  name             = var.lambda_authorizer_name
}
```

Someone has any idea that can help me to solve this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set [authorization_type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_route#authorization_type) in `aws_apigatewayv2_route` to `CUSTOM`.